# Transforming the sum of min functions into one min function with the aim of translating the max-min problem into the linear program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have to solve the following optimization problem:

> $\text{For } x\in \mathbb{R}^+, \ \ \alpha, \beta, \omega_i, \pi_i \in \mathbb{R}^+, \ i \in \{ 1, \dots, s \}, \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^s \pi_i=1 \text{ and } \alpha<\beta \Rightarrow  $
>   $$\text{max}_{x} \left[ - \alpha x +\beta \sum_{i=1}^{s} \pi_i \text{min}(x, \omega_i)   \right]. $$

If I understood the source material right, in order to translate this problem into the LP problem, we first have to get it in the form:

> $$\text{max}_x  \ \text{min}_{k=1,\dots, K} \{ a_k  \ x  \}.$$

So, in an attempt to do that, I was trying to somehow transform the sum of the min functions:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{s} \pi_i \text{min}(x, \omega_i),$$
into one min function.

If I omit the weights $\pi_i$ for a moment, and assume that for any $i,j \in \{ 1, \dots, s \}, \ i \neq j,$ we have $\omega_i<\omega_j$, it seems to me that the next equality holds:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{s} \text{min}(x, \omega_i) = \text{min} (sx, \omega_1 + (s-1)x, \omega_1 + \omega_2 + (s-2)x, \dots, \sum_{j=1}^{s-1}\omega_j +x, \sum_{j=1}^s \omega_j). 
\end{equation}

I'm not sure if that equality holds though. I've unsuccessfully tried proving it by induction but I've tested it graphically in some "small" cases and also simply by covering all possible cases regarding "between which "$\omega$"s could $x$ be". It seems reasonable to me - like it should work? And in the context of the optimization, it really simplifies the whole thing cause I just end up with the linear functions of $x$ which I sort by their slopes, compute the intersections of each two consecutive ones and the "highest" intersection is my solution?

If that previous equality really holds and my reasoning described in the previous paragraph is correct, I have no idea what to do once I include those weights $\pi_i$ into the picture?

Thanks for any help/insight in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be dealt with using some inequalities:

$$
\begin{align}
   \max\> & -\alpha x +\beta \sum_i \pi_i y_i \\
          & y_i \le x \\
          & y_i \le \omega_i
\end{align}
$$

This works as $\beta \ge 0, \pi_i \ge 0$